# Android Adapter and Filter for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

I really ain't able to create an Adapter to give to an AutoCompleteTextView.
I have this class, MyObject with the methods

```
 String getString()
 Bitmap getBitmap()
```

In the adapter I wanna show both of them, and obviously I want the textView to be completed with myObject.getString(), the thing I ain't able to do is to override the Filter's methods
performingFilter e filterResults. Can someone please show me an easy example? Thank you =)

Comment: see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: of course,  you need to return one more column in the Cursor if you need to show one more field in the dropdown menu